# What is the most reliable part of the user-agent string to detect Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, firefox, cross-browser, http-headers

For example, does the version token always start with MSIE using Internet Explorer?

Can MSIE show up as the token of another browser?

Thank You.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Not an answer, but you might find the list of user agents to be useful: [Firefox User Agent List](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Firefox/) and [IE User Agent List](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is ***no*** part of the HTTP_USER_AGENT string that is reliable. Some browsers masquerade as others; and users can change that string any old time.

This isn't part of your question, but I'll just go on with my spoutfest anyway.

The practice of trying to identify the user agent by its HTTP_USER_AGENT is called "browser sniffing," pretty widely agreed to be a Bad Thing.

The better way, they say, is to test for versions of IE; and to test for the presence of browser-version specific features. There's an interesting and expert discussion of browser detection here:

http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/

**EDIT** 20110516: c /HTTP_REFERER/HTTP_USER_AGENT/ g  Sorry for that stupid mistake.